# How to copy MongoDB databases using PHP now that copydb is deprecated

Tags: php, mongodb

In MongoDB version 4.2 `copydb` and its `copyDatabase` wrapper have been deprecated. The MongoDB manual suggests that we should now use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`. But I was calling the copy command from PHP using the PHP MongoDB driver and the dump and restore commands are commands that need to be run from the command line and don't have any PHP equivalent. How can I now copy a database using PHP?

Comment: Even tho it's possible to run mongodump/mongorestore from PHP with shell_exec kind of functions, it's hardly feasible to download the whole database to the client and then upload it back.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your workflow. Do you simply want to create a db backup/restore on the machine or do you want to provide an up/download of the same through a website/service (via php)?

Comment: I want to copy a database for testing purposes. We have a database with all our initial setup for testing and I want to copy it to the test database before tests are run. This was usually initiated remotely through a request handled by PHP

Comment: Just to clarify why some internal solution would be great: on systems like Debian or Alpine (in former versions that still shipped MongoDB), you had to install another package for additionall shell tools. These might not be present on all systems that have a running MongoDB setup

Answer (score 3):

You can use "mongodump" and "mongorestore" as you mentioned as well. In PHP, you can use shell_exec to run the commands. For example:

```
$backUpCommand = "mongodump --archive='/tmp/mongodump-dev-db' --db=dev";
shell_exec($backUpCommand);

$restoreCommand = "mongorestore --archive='/tmp/mongodump-dev-db' --db=test --nsFrom='test.*' --nsTo='examples.*'";
shell_exec($restoreCommand);
```

Please note nsFrom and nsTo are to rename the namespace if you need it. See more details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore).

In case you want to copy the dump to another host, try combining --host params of mongorestore. So, in that case, your restore command would be:

```
$restoreCommand = "mongorestore --host=mongodb1.example.net --port=27017 --username=user --password=$PSWD --authenticationDatabase=admin --archive='/tmp/mongodump-dev-db' --db=test";
shell_exec($restoreCommand);
```

Comment: It is possible but it significantly complicates application setup with external CLI dependencies, it will require to reserve significant SDD space on all application servers to dump the database (multiple times in case of concurrent requests), it will incur data transfer costs and may be quite slow. In other words - it's okay as a one-off manual job but not for production systems.

Comment: Agree with Alex Blex. This "solution" is just 100% more complex than the previous alternative